# Trouble installing BuckleScript on Windows

Tags: npm, installation, bucklescript

I am trying to install BuckleScript on Windows. I use the following command:

```
npm install -g bs-platform
```

and I get this error:

```
[31mninja: fatal: [0mCreateProcess: Wersja %1 nie jest zgodna z wersją uruchomionego systemu Windows. Sprawdź informacje dotyczące systemu operacyjnego na tym komputerze, a następnie skontaktuj się z wydawcą oprogramowania.


child_process.js:650
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Filip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bs-platform\lib\ninja.exe -f release.ninja
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
    at buildLibs (C:\Users\Filip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bs-platform\scripts\install.js:290:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Filip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bs-platform\scripts\install.js:331:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
[37;40mnpm[0m [0m[31;40mERR![0m [0m[35mcode[0m ELIFECYCLE
[0m[37;40mnpm[0m [0m[31;40mERR![0m [0m[35merrno[0m 1
[0m[37;40mnpm[0m [0m[31;40mERR![0m[35m[0m bs-platform@5.0.4 postinstall: `node scripts/install.js`
[0m[37;40mnpm[0m [0m[31;40mERR![0m[35m[0m Exit status 1
[0m[37;40mnpm[0m [0m[31;40mERR![0m[35m[0m 
[0m[37;40mnpm[0m [0m[31;40mERR![0m[35m[0m Failed at the bs-platform@5.0.4 postinstall script.
[0m[37;40mnpm[0m [0m[31;40mERR![0m[35m[0m This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[0m
[37;40mnpm[0m [0m[31;40mERR![0m[35m[0m A complete log of this run can be found in:
[0m[37;40mnpm[0m [0m[31;40mERR![0m[35m[0m     C:\Users\Filip\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-14T14_21_01_235Z-debug.log
[0m
```

The message in Polish means that "version %1 is not compatible with the Windows version running". Any ideas?

Comment: Create an issue here to get the attention of the maintainer: https://github.com/BuckleScript/bucklescript/issues

Answer (score 0):

[Answered by the maintainer on Github](https://github.com/BuckleScript/bucklescript/issues/3607#issuecomment-502312691):

> Indeed, currently we only support Windows 64 bit, the compiler is prebuilt on 64 bit machine.